# Problema al crear un proyecto de Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify

cada que intento crear un proyecto de vue, me aparece el siguiente error en la consola. Alguna ayuda, para solucionarlo, gracias.

npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USUARIO\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-07-25T23_50_10_238Z-debug-0.log
ERROR  Error: command failed: npm install --loglevel error --legacy-peer-deps
Error: command failed: npm install --loglevel error --legacy-peer-deps
at ChildProcess.
(C:\Users\USUARIO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli\lib\util\executeCommand.js:138:16)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:537:28)
at cp.emit (C:\Users\USUARIO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli\node_modules\cross-
spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español! Lee [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y [haz el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla. Por favor lee el mensaje de error y aclara lo que hayas investigado en base a lo que interpretas. Por ejemplo para "This is a problem related to network connectivity.
In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.", aclara si estás detrás de un proxy o no.

Comment: O si revisaste los logs como te sugiere "A complete log of this run can be found in:
C:\Users\USUARIO\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-07-25T23_50_10_238Z-debug-0.log", etc

Comment: Puedes editar la prgunta presionando en [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/548372/edit) y agregar la información para que podamos ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de instalar vuecli asegurate de instalar yarn:
yarn install
Instala vuecli:
yarn global add @vue/cli
Crea tu proyecto en vue de esta manera:
vue create hello-world

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).